# How to change my flutter text field twice after already using one text editing controller

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a text field that changes its text after an action, but the issue is I want to change the same text field twice but I can only do it from one text editing controller, how can I change the same text field from two different functions? Only one text editing controller is working, if I use the same controller in a different function for a different use it doesn't work, what to do? Thanks

here is the code, i first declared the text editing controller

```
class MapSampleState extends State < MapSample > {

String _userDestination =" ";
Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
var locationText = TextEditingController();
var locationText2 = TextEditingController();
```

then assigned it to my text editing field

```
Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,

  child: Container(


         height:50,
                    width: 50, margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 100,bottom: 20,right: 10),

                    child: Align (alignment: Alignment.topRight,

         child: new FloatingActionButton(onPressed:clearMyMap,
             heroTag: "btn1",
         tooltip: "Cancel Trip",
         backgroundColor:Colors.white,
         child: Icon(Icons.cancel, color:Colors.black,),
         ),
                    )
      )

),
```

this is the first place i use locatonText text editing controller

```
void _getLatLng(Prediction prediction) async {
    GoogleMapsPlaces _places = new 
       GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey:"AIzaSyD8lTNVJ5LLPYSdahUh9tlO8rFeskzZw8E");  //Same API_KEY as above

if (prediction!=null ){

    PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
        await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(prediction.placeId);
    double latitude = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
    double longitude = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;
    String address = prediction.description;
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++address+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
appState.sendRequest(address);
    locationText.text ="$address";

  }


}
```

this is the second place i use locatonText text editing controller

```
void clearMyMap(){


appState.clearMap();
locationText.clear();




}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: i edited my post

Comment: In your second code segment, I don't see where you assign your text editing controller to your text field. I just see a Container with a Button in it.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that, I fixed it and it worked